# Hibernate search in string array

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, hql

I am new to hibernate and looking for 
a) A solutions
and b) comparison of solutions in terms of performance and query complexity.

Example entity - (Assume required hibernate annotations)

```
Class Ent{
String name;
List<String> alias;
}
```

I need a solution which can search for a string 'example' in name and alias array in a single database query.

I am able to do this using hibernate with RAW sql ( select * ...). Can somebody suggest a better solution using HQl, Criteria, etc.. with reason

Comment: I believe you wanted to say HQL.. I tried using HQL but facing issues as hibernate is not supporting ANY operator present in SQL. I am working with the IN operator..

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `alias` can be empty:

```
select distinct e from Ent e left outer join e.alias a 
where e.name like :term or a.name like :term
```

or:

```
select e from Ent e
where e.name like :term
 or e.id in
  (select e2.id from Ent e2 join e2.alias a where a.name like :term)
```

I prefer the second option because it should be faster (no `distinct`) and because it allows easier paging of the results.